# How to detect RAM that was added after Ubuntu installation?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, ram

While I installed ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) on my system, I attached 2gb ram to only one slot.

Now, after weeks I've attached another 2gb ram to another slot. Ubuntu does not detect 4gb of memory in total. It just detects 2gb. Do we need to install additional ram using some command?

In BIOS there is a note something like: `memory used is less than available. Note that some OS may not use complete memory.`

Comment: How much RAM do you see in your BIOS?

Comment: it shows 2gb there

Comment: Ubuntu runs at a higher level than your BIOS, and it cannot detect RAM that is not detected by your BIOS. I'd suggest try to reseat your RAM, and making sure if its not defective.

Comment: Please add information about mainboard/laptop maker and model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu uses all the available RAM detected by your BIOS - there are no special commands that need to be given to detect additional RAM. In this case the problem seems to be that your BIOS is not using the added memory.

First, try using another slot for the memory. This might show if the used memory slot is defective. Then you should try if it is detected by another, compatible, computer. If not, it is likely defective.

Comment: There is some problem with one of the slot in my laptop.